# format a file content using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Hello everyone I'm a beginner in shell coding. In daily basis I need to convert a file's data to another format, I usually do it manually with Text Editor. But I often do mistakes. So I decided to code an easy script who can do the work for me. The file's content like this

```
/release201209
a1,a2,"a3",a4,a5
b1,b2,"b3",b4,b5
c1,c2,"c3",c4,c5
```

to this:

```
a2>a3
b2>b3
c2>c3
```

The script should ignore the first line and print the second and third values separated by '>'
I'm half way there, and here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 | sed '1d' | cut -d, -f2-3 | tr -d '"' > $2
```

It was working well until I found out that it is not working for a type of data containing comma in a3 like this one:
`data,VERSION,"FUNDS.TRANSFER,ASS.VERS.TIERS.BOP",,` 
Which returns
`VERSION>FUNDS.TRANSFER` 
instead of
`VERSION>FUNDS.TRANSFER,ASS.VERS.TIERS.BOP`

Can you help me out updating it please ? Thanks

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650812/12957340) `awk -vFPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' '{print $2 ">" $3}' file` will do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping separator within double quotes, in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804673/escaping-separator-within-double-quotes-in-awk)

Comment: It returns 
awk: invalid -v option

Comment: Try GNU awk: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Installation.html

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), and you should [quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a proper CSV parsing tool like `csvtool` to extract the relevant columns (its much easier & more reliable than rolling out your own parsing). Then, use `tr`/`sed` to do the necessary transformations:

```
sed '1d' file.txt | csvtool -t ',' col 2,3 - | tr -d '"' | sed 's/,/>/'
```

**Steps:**

- Remove the header line using `sed`
- Use `csvtool` to extract the 2nd and 3rd columns
- Use `tr` to remove the double quotes
- Use `sed` to map the *first* `,` to a `>` (you can't use `tr` for this since that does a global translation)

---

You can install `csvtool` with your package manager, e.g. on a Debian-based system `sudo apt-get install csvtool`. Replace `apt-get` with your package manager on other systems e.g. `yum`, `brew`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a CSV module included:

```sh
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.read(ARGV.shift).map {|row| 
    printf "%s>%s\n", row[1], row[2]
  }
' file | sed 1d
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrsBF.jpg)

hello sir I'm also learning a shell script, what do you want like that ??

this is my code

```
function klir(){
line2=$(cut -d\, -f1 $1 > $1.temp.filterline2)
line3=$(cut -d\" -f2 $1 > $1.temp.filterline3)
paste $1.temp.filterline2 $1.temp.filterline3 | sed "s/\t/>/g ; 1d"
rm $1.temp.filterline2 $1.temp.filterline3 2>/dev/null 
}
klir $1
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer
I want something like that VERSION>FUNDS.TRANSFER,ASS.VERS.TIERS.BOP
secondValue>thirdValue

Comment: Plase [don't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)